# Spring Integration - file adapter

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-integration

I'm newbie to Spring, I am writing a file adapter which reads file from the input folder and move the files to output folder. I played with the following examples but there are some points that are not clear to me.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                              directory="C:\Users\my\Desktop\files\in"
                              filename-regex="[a-z]+.txt">
    <integration:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="strings"/>

<integration:channel id="strings"/> 

<integration:service-activator input-channel="strings"
                               output-channel="filesOut"
                               ref="handler"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="C:\Users\my\Desktop\files\out"/>

<bean id="handler" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.filecopy.Handler"/>
```

I have few more questions regarding the above file.

1. I don't have a clear idea about the `<integration:channel id="strings"/>` tag. Why its just string. What are the other possible values which can be used instead `strings`.
2. As I tested `input-channel` of the `integration:service-activator` and `output-channel` of the `file-to-string-transformer` has nothing to do with `<integration:channel id="strings"/>` is it correct?
3. `handler` bean which is used in `integration:service-activator` has 3 methods.

   ```
   public class Handler {

   public String handleString(String input) {
       System.out.println("Copying text: " + input);
       return input.toUpperCase();
   }

   public File handleFile(File input) {
       System.out.println("Copying file: " + input.getAbsolutePath());
       return input;
   }

   public byte[] handleBytes(byte[] input) {
       System.out.println("Copying " + input.length + " bytes ...");
       return new String(input).toUpperCase().getBytes();
   } }
   ```

   And currently it fires only one method which is `handleString(String whichTakesString)` is it because of the `<integration:service-activator input-channel="strings"` ? How can I call the other methods, what is the way to do it. I tried to figure this out many ways but still no chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it looks like you haven't got enough theoretical knowledges, so consider to read the books: [EIP Book](http://www.eaipatterns.com), [Spring Integration in Action](http://www.manning.com/fisher).

In general `MessageChannel` is a concept to carry messages between services via loosely-coupling manner.

`strings` is just a **bean name** and it can be any value. `<integration:channel>` is just a custom tag, which produces a `MessageChannel` in the end. To be more comfortable with that you should to read the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/).

Since you use `<file:file-to-string-transformer>`, the result of this component will be `String` file representation.

Your `<service-activator>` invokes `handleString` method of your `Handler` because the runtime `payload` argument type resolution.

To make it worked with other methods you should use appropriate transformer (`<file:file-to-bytes-transformer>`) or don't use it at all - the `<file:inbound-channel-adapter>` produces `File` object as `payload` for resulting message.